# Concat an string as an object property

Tags: javascript, string, object, concatenation

So, I'm receiving a string named "desktop", which is, actually, a property of my obj.

So, as a property it should look like `obj.desktop`.
I've been trying to concat this the way it follows:

```
oJSonElementByIndex +"["+"'desktop'"+"]"
```

And also:

```
oJSonElementByIndex + "." + "desktop"
```

But it always looks like this:

```
"[object Object]['detalleDesktop']"
```

Any ideas on what's wrong? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `oJSonElementByIndex` look like and how does it relate to `obj`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a property name of an object stored in a string you can access the property value via the `[]` bracket notation, putting the variable in the brackets as shown below.

```
var desktop = 'some_proprty_name';
...
var value = oJSonElementByIndex[desktop];
```

Comment: You're awesome. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You were almost good :

```
v = "desktop"
oJSonElementByIndex[v]
oJSonElementByIndex["desktop"]
```

string + object = string + object.toString() :

```
({}).toString() // "[object Object]"
({}) + "" // "[object Object]"
```